# Can I copy multiple named files on the Windows command line using a single "copy" command?

Tags: windows, command-line, post-build-event

I'd like to copy several known files to another directory as a part of a post-build event, but I don't want to have lines and lines of "copy [file] [destination] [switches]" in my build event.

If possible, I'd like to list out the files I'd like to copy using a similar format: "copy [file 1] [file 2] [file 3] [etc...] [destination] [switches]". However, Windows doesn't seem to like this type of format. How can I do it?

Comment: [Can Windows' copy command handle multiple files?](https://superuser.com/q/168336/241386)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use 'for' either in a batch file or directly from the command prompt:

```
for %I in (file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt) do copy %I c:\somedir\
```

Wildcards are supported in the filelist as well:

```
for %I in (*.txt *.doc *.html) do copy %I c:\somedir\
```

For more info, just type for /? from a command prompt, or for a much easier to read help use Start->Help and Support and search for "For". On my XP Pro box, it was item 15 in the full text search results.

Comment: Works like a charm! The only thing is that I have to double up my percent signs when used in a build event (i.e. for %%I in...). Thanks!!

Comment: IF the files are in sub folders add `/f` like `for /f %%I in (*.txt *.doc *.html) do copy %I c:\somedir\ `

Answer (score 34):

XP and Vista replaced **xcopy** with **robocopy**, and it will do exactly what you want.  The syntax for what you want feels backwards at first, but it does the job:

```
robocopy source\folder a\dest\folder file1.exe file2.bat file3.dll file4.txt
```

Comment: (older versions at least) of XP don't include robocopy, you need to install if from something like the windows 2003 server resource kit: http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en

Comment: @Dolphin: good catch; I had it on my XP machines and didn't remember installing it myself, but you're right.

Comment: Neither XP nor Vista "replaced" xcopy. It's still there.

Comment: @Timwi, poorly phrased on my part.  What I meant is that it was replaced as the preferred way to copy multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`<Copy>` MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx).

Comment: The question does not suggest .NET is even installed, and that would require developing an MS Build script. It's already cumbersome just to do a command line copy; why add all that on top?

Comment: the question talks about copying "as a part of a post-build event". using MSBuild was natural for me.

Comment: @DavidSchmitt I think this is what I want but I'm not sure how I can use this in a build event. Can you show syntax for doing that?

Comment: You insert this directly into the msbuild/csproj file as XML.