# Copying of file using .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I have written the following code and am trying to copy all the files to the location. The following line works when I paste it on `cmd` but it doesn't work in the batch file:

```
for %I in (*.m) do (copy /Y %I "%appdata%\Math\include")
pause
```

Kindly, let me know what I am missing?

I have tried to follow the answers from here: [Can I copy multiple named files on the Windows command line using a single "copy" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922607/can-i-copy-multiple-named-files-on-the-windows-command-line-using-a-single-copy)
But no use to me. Please share your suggestions.

Comment: Double the percents, `@For %%I In (*.m) Do @Copy /Y "%%I" "%AppData%\Math\include"`. _Although you don't really need a `For` loop, `Copy /Y *.m "%AppData%\Math\include"`_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `copy` or `xcopy`:

```
copy /y *.m newDir
```

However, if `newDir` does not exist `copy` will create a file named `newDir`

To avoid that `xcopy /i` can be used instead:

```
xcopy /y /i *.m newDir
```

To include subdirectories use `xcopy /s`:

```
xcopy /y /i /s *.m newDir

or shorter:

xcopy /yis *.m newDir
```

There is also the newer [Robocopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy).

Comment: Yes I got it. But what if the scenario changes and I need to copy more than one I type of extension files? That's why I am trying to use such a looping method.

Comment: @JafferWilson like `for %I in (com bat exe) do copy "*.%I" ""%appdata%\Math\include"`

Comment: @JafferWilson For multiple extensions you could indeed use the loop, or multiple xcopy commands.